# как правильно инициализировать маркеры на карте google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api

Есть карта google map. На ней динамично ставлю маркеры, сам маркер подбираю через сервис geocode по адресу, который возвращает координаты, но если адреса объектов одинаковые тогда возвращает все маркеры в кучу и даже если максимально приблизить карту то на ней не отобразятся объекты а просто пятно с группой объектов. Группировка маркеров полезна когда смотришь глобально, но при сближении она должна показывать конкретные маркеры объектов. Как мне при максимальном сближении карты выводить все маркеры в группе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$('.b-data').each(function() {
    city = $.trim($(this).find('.b-city').text());

    coords = geo_code(city+''+$(this).find('.bcity').attr('address'));  // функция геокода

    /* Добавление маркера на карту */
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:EGMap0, position:new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng), title:'Test1 Name_Test1', raiseOnDrag:true});

     markers.push(marker);
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
         EGMap0_info_window.setContent("<div class=\"got\"><img src=\"http://zrobyt.com.ua/img/img_prev.jpg\"><a style=\"margin-left:5px;\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"/ru/user/profile/91\">Test1 Name_Test1</a><br>"+$(this).find('.b-cat').html()+" </div>");
            EGMap0_info_window.open(EGMap0,marker);
    });
});
```

Функция геокодера

```
function geo_code(keyword) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json';
    var lat = 0;
    var lng = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        async:false,
        data:{ address:keyword },
        success:function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'OK') {
                lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

            }
        },
    });
    return {'lat':lat, 'lng':lng};

}
var EGMapMarkerClusterer11= new MarkerClusterer(EGMap0,markers,{});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var EGMapMarkerClusterer11 = new MarkerClusterer(EGMap0, markers, {
    maxZoom: 10, // зум, дальше которого кластер рассыпается на маркеры,
    gridSize: 60 // размер квадрата в пикселях, по которому маркеры объединяются в кластеры
});
```